# Adjust visible text in Vertex Nodes

Tags: palantir-foundry

Is it possible to adjust the amount of text visible for Vertex nodes?

I'm interested in using Vertex to simulate and diagram our dataflow processes and throughput, but having trouble with the legibility of nodes, i.e. modest amounts of text on Vertex nodes are cut off:

[image]

Ideally I'm looking for a setting that would autofit nodes to text in selected properties or enable specification of node dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under layer styling for the layer of that node, you can change the node style to “Object card”, which is a wider node style that lends itself better to longer labels. If you select an object like the one backing the node in the screenshot, you can also press the triple-dot menu next to a property and add a property readout. This can be useful in one-off cases to display longer property values. There is currently no way to change the set the sizes of node to custom values.

[Object card node style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3URgu.png)

[Property readout example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJDlR.png)

Comment: I'm actually using the Object card setting in the above. Having a feature like the above described would help our adoption of this exciting new product app. We'll try the property readout - Thanks!